# How do I use sampling method in PySpark for Large Dataset?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata, sampling

I'm actually working with a large dataset ( 87,56,685 ) Consisting of `USERID`, `MOVIEID` and `RATING`
and I need to use sampling method on rating to reduce the dataset size i'm limited to use only Sampling strategy.

I tried this way of doing it

```
DataFrame = DataFrame.sampleBy("Rating", fractions={1:0.2, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2, 4: 0.2, 5: 0.2}, seed=0)
DataFrame.show()
```

and my rmse value is greater than 3.

can someone help me with sampling method on large datasets ?

with some example code?

Comment: What is wrong with the existing MLLib documentation? With _any dataset_ , you can end up with overfitting, regardless of size

Comment: I used the MLlib documentation as well and couldn't able to find how to use sampling method if you could provide me a sample code/example on how to use sampling method on ratings it would be really helpful.

Comment: I haven't used this `sampleBy`/`fractions` API before... I usually split 80/20 into sample/test data. There is sample code in Spark GIthub for most functions, though.

Comment: Thank you very much on the information.